# Why "permission denied" when running `less` with chmod 6110?

Tags: permissions, setuid, setgid

Assume you are user `x`, so running `id` gives

```
uid=1001(x) gid=1001(x) groups=1001(x)
```

And there is also a user `y` with

```
uid=1002(y) gid=1002(y) groups=1002(y)
```

Now as `root` we create a file `readme` in user's `x` home directory like this:

```
# cd /home/x
# touch readme
# echo "hello" > readme
# chown root:y readme
# chmod 640 readme
```

And we make a copy of `less`

```
# cd /home/x
# cp /usr/bin/less .
# chown y:x less
# chmod 6110 less
```

**I would expect user `x` to be able to read `readme` by running `./less readme`** because of the setuid and setgid, but I get a "permission denied" error. **Why?**

This is my logic, but probably something is wrong.

`chmod 6110` gives *only* execution rights to the owner (`y`) and members of the group (`x`). Since user `x` belongs to group `x`, he can execute `less`. Then the setuid makes the effective UID to be the same as `y`, and the setgid makes the effective GID the same as the group of the owner, again `y`. And since `readme`'s group is `y`, `less` should have read permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies here:

> the setgid makes the effective GID the same as the group of the owner, again `y`.

The setgid bit causes the effective gid to be that of the owner group of the binary, which is `x` here (`chmod y:x less`).

`less` ends up running with an effective uid corresponding to `y`’s, and an effective gid corresponding to `x`’s. Since `readme` is owned by `root:y`, it can’t be read.